# Error when try to save another format using tiles in Python

Tags: python, windows, image-slicer

I am trying to save a image using tiles and image_slicer. The default format is PNG, but I need to save as JPG and whent I try that I receive the error below.

KeyError: 'JPG'

I followed the documentation

This is my code:

```
tiles = image_slicer.slice(path+image_file_name, 4, save=False)
    image_slicer.save_tiles(tiles, prefix='slice_'+names_images, format='JPG', directory='../images/mar2020/selected/resized/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the documentation is wrong. Try to use `jpeg` instead of `jpg` (case insensitive).

[source](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html)

Comment: Looks like i found the problem. Its possible that the documentation is outdated and the library it uses(pillow) changed its formats. I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Im talking about the image_slicer documentation which op mentioned

Comment: Sorry about the late.. I used jpeg and it works. Thank you